# Map a dictionary with another dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, mapping

I am pretty sure that I must be missing something really basic but, is there a way to map a dictionary with another one?.

For instance given a dictionary like this:

```
d = {'a': {'b': 'r1', 'c': 'r2'}, 'v': {'x': 'r4', 'o': 'r2'}}
```

And use a mapper like this:

```
mapper = {'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'v': 3, 'x': 4, 'o': 5}
```

The expected output should be like this:

```
result = {0: {1: 'r1', 2: 'r2'}, 3: {4: 'r4', 5: 'r2'}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a function that recursively replaces keys with corresponding values in the mapper dict:

```
def map_keys(d, m):
    return {m[k]: map_keys(v, m) for k, v in d.items()} if isinstance(d, dict) else d
```

so that `map_keys(d, mapper)` returns:

```
{0: {1: 'r1', 2: 'r2'}, 3: {4: 'r4', 5: 'r2'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not recursive, hence only works for similar input (if you're fine):

```
d = {'a': {'b': 'r1', 'c': 'r2'}, 'v': {'x': 'r4', 'o': 'r2'}}
mapper = {'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'v': 3, 'x': 4, 'o': 5}

res = {}
for k, v in d.items():
    res.update({mapper[k]: {mapper[x]: y for x, y in v.items()}})

print(res)
# {0: {1: 'r1', 2: 'r2'}, 3: {4: 'r4', 5: 'r2'}}
```

**Shorter**:

```
res = {mapper[k]: {mapper[x]: y for x, y in v.items()} for k, v in d.items()}
```